# Router "ZXHN H168N V3.1" can't be port forwarded (after doing so, there are no visible open ports) in context of Acore server

Tags: azerothcore

The router I attempted to port forward to enable WAN connections was "ZXHN H168N V3.1", I portforwarded the 8085 & the 3724 ports.

I tried lowering the firewall on the router.

I tried completely disabling the firewall on my pc, and also added exceptions for the authserver.exe (acore authentication server) & the worldserver.exe .

The server works completely fine on LAN, I can connect via my local IPV4 and by localhost(127.0.0.1), but I can not through my WAN address, and canyouseeme.org says the ports that I supposedly opened are closed.

Answer (score 1):

Did you configure your realmlist table as described in https://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/Installation / 6) Setting up the database?

You need to set your local IP to be able to connect from other machines than locally.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/10jourx
When I sent client realmlist to 192.168.1.4 it connects, when I set it to my WAN it doesn't.